# Check if winston metadata is "empty" after format.metadata

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

This "[Complete Winston Logger Guide](https://coralogix.com/blog/complete-winston-logger-guide-with-hands-on-examples/)", gives the following example:

```
const myFormat = printf( ({ level, message, timestamp , ...metadata}) => {
  let msg = `${timestamp} [${level}] : ${message} `  
  if(metadata) {
    msg += JSON.stringify(metadata)
  }
  return msg
});
```

which I'm trying to implement; however, I can't get the test for the existence of metadata to work. First, I *always* have metadata. I presume that's because I'm using `format.metadata` earlier in the process. Here's my Winston setup:

```
const logger = createLogger({
  level: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'info' : 'debug',
  defaultMeta: {
    service: 'lp-server'
  },
  format: format.combine(
    format.timestamp({
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
    }),
    format.errors({ stack: true }),
    format.splat(),
    format.metadata({ fillExcept: [
      'timestamp',
      'level',
      'service',
      'label',
      'message'
    ]}),
  ),
  transports: [
    new transports.Console({
      level: 'debug',
      format: format.combine(
        consoleFormat // my implementation of the example, which we'll get to, below
      )
    })
  ]
});
```

Now, if I do a log entry, say

```
logger.debug(`PROD is ${PROD} and NODE_ENV is ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`);
```

if in my custom format I console log the full `info` object, I get

```
{
  timestamp: '2022-07-21 13:14:40',
  level: 'debug',
  service: 'lp-server',
  label: undefined,
  message: 'PROD is false and NODE_ENV is undefined',
  metadata: {},
  [Symbol(level)]: 'debug'
}
```

And if I destructure `info` the way they did in their example and console log the `metadata`, it throws both `metadata` and `[Symbol(level]` in there:

```
// console.log('Got metadata');
// console.dir(metadata);
Got metadata
{ metadata: {}, [Symbol(level)]: 'debug' }
```

So, my custom format function now looks like this:

```
const consoleFormat = format.printf( (
  {
    timestamp,
    level,
    service,
    label = '',
    message,
    ...metadata
  }
)  => {
  let msg = `${timestamp} ${level} ${service}`;
  if (label) msg += ` [${label}]`;
  msg += `: ${message}`;

  if (metadata.metadata !== {})  msg += ' ' + JSON.stringify(metadata.metadata);

  return msg;
});
```

If I'm actually intentionally logging some additional metadata, that works great; but, aside from the issue of having to juggle the `metadata.metadata` thing, I can't get the test to work — it always returns `true`. I've tried

```
(metadata.metadata)
(metadata.metadata !== {})
(metadata.metadata !== '{}')
(metadata.metadata !== '\{\}')
```

What's the right way to get this to work? Either by testing for what I guess is an object that exists but has no properties, or, better, by resolving my `metadata.metadata` issue?

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for the answer to this, but reading your question made me figure out one possible answer:

```
let metadataString = JSON.stringify(metadata.metadata);
if (metadataString  !== '{}')  msg += ' ' + metadataString;
```